# Give me such $p_1, q_1$ or $p_2,q_2$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$, $f^{i}(n)=1$ and $g^{j}(n)=1$

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples, collatz-conjecture

I'm sorry , If this is a similar question. Because, I could not get a satisfactory answer. But, I hope,this question is not similar.

Let $$ f(n)=
\begin{cases}
p_1\times n + q_1          & \text {if $n$ is odd} \\
\frac{n}{2}   & \text {if $n$ is even} 
\end{cases} ,$$ Here $p_1,q_1\in
\mathbb{N}$

Let $$ g(n) =
\begin{cases}
p_2 \times n - q_2        & \text {if $n$ is odd} \\
\frac{n}{2}   & \text {if $n$ is even} 
\end{cases} ,$$ Here $p_2,q_2\in
\mathbb{N}$

***Example-1***

We know that, if $p_1=3$ and $q_1=1$ for **any $n\in\mathbb N$** (There is no counter-example,for now ) , we can find such $"i"$ number, which that it must be $f^{i}(n)=1$.

***Example-2***

If $p_1=3$ and $q_1=5$ for **any $n\in\mathbb N$** , we can not find such $"i"$ number, $f^{i}(n)=1$. (Because there are many counter-examples; $\Rightarrow 5,19,23,187,347$ and for any $"i"$ number $f^{i}(n)≠1$.)

***Example-3***

If $p_2=3$ and $q_2=1$ for **any $n\in\mathbb N$** , we can not find such $"j"$ number, $g^{j}(n)=1$. (Because there are many counter-examples; $\rightarrow 5,7; 17,25,37,55,41,61,91$ and for any $"j"$ number $g^{j}(n)≠1$.)

> Finally, The question:
>
> Give me such $p_1, q_1$ or $p_2,q_2$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$,  $f^{i}(n)=1$ and $g^{j}(n)=1$,  **as a $"3n+1$ problem** .
>   Are such numbers known, other than $"3n+1"$ ?

($p_1≠3$ and $q_1≠1$,  because this conjecture is Collatz Conjecture, I already know)

*Note: (If you find any mistakes ,please, edit or improve my question for me.Thanks, so much!)*

Comment: We don't know that for $3n + 1$ there aren't any numbers that don't reach 1. It's an open problem.

Comment: I know, this is not my question.

Comment: well, you do state so in example 1.

Comment: What's the question?  You just want some example of a pseudo-Collatz problem that does work?  Try something like $n_i=1=q_i$.  In those cases, even numbers go to $\frac n2$ and odd numbers go to $\frac {n\pm 1}2$ (after two steps).  Either way, it goes down (unless $n=1$).

Comment: @Lulu, this is not conjecture, your example is  mathematical reality.

Comment: I don't understand.  Your example $1$ is not an example at all, because it is an open problem.  Unless I erred (always possible) the examples I wrote down can be demonstrated.

Comment: Lulu, please understand me correct. These are " example".which that I try what I want to say. This is not answer.And your example not conecture.This is mathematical realty.

Comment: If you know, what I want to say, please edit my question.

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea what you are asking.  I thought you were asking for a variant of the Collatz problem which actually could be shown to have an affirmative solution.  If you meant something else, then of course my examples are unlikely to help.

Comment: Yes understand me correct, I find "alternative" $3n+1$ problem.My english so bad..can you edit for me?

Comment: I've just deleted my answer. Most likely I do not correctly understand your question, so it seems better to keep distraction away... Sorry for not being able to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, to my knowledge, a $p_1$ $=$ 3 and $p_2$ $=$ 1 for $f(n)$ is the only combination with the behavior that matches the Collatz Conjecture. However, if you expand $n$ so $n \in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ , then the rule $p_1=$ 3 and $p_1=$ 1 for $g(n)$ will behave exactly like the Collatz Conjecture, only with negative numbers.

ex)

$f(n)$ , $p_1=$ 3 and $p_1=$ 1  --> 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, ...

$g(n)$ , $p_1=$ 3 and $p_1=$ 1  --> -26, -13, -40, -20, -10, -5, -16, -8, -4, -2, -1, ...

However, the Collatz Conjecture's behavior is not exclusive to these rules. If the other loops are ignored for the rule $f(n)$ where $p_1 =$ 3 and $p_2 >$ 1, Collatz-like behavior can be found amoung the values where $n\in p_2* \mathbb{Z}$ . The only difference is the scale by $p_2$.

ex)

$f(n)$ , $p_1=$ 3 and $p_1=$ 1  --> 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, ...

$f(n)$ , $p_1=$ 3 and $p_1=$ 5  --> 130, 65, 200, 100, 50, 25, 80, 40, 20, 10, ...

If reaching 1 is desired, then $p_1$ $=$ 1 and $p_2$ $=$ 1 for $f(n)$ will reduce to 1 without any loops or counter examples to anyone's knowledge.

If looking for rules with one and only one loop is desired, then the rules $p_1$ $=$ 3 and $p_2$ $=$ 3 for $f(n)$ and $p_1$ $=$ 3 and $p_2$ $=$ 9 for $f(n)$ may work. There are no known counter examples as of now to these rules not reaching their trivial cycles.